# \setstretch doesn't work using abntex template

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, setspace

I'm trying to change the line space of my document. I used `\linespread` but it changes also the `toc` line space, and I don't want this.
So I tried `\setstretch` but it doesn't work.

I believe that I don't need to attach a image to the question. Here is a sample document which I'm working https://github.com/guylhermetabosa/TCC/tree/master/modelo-tcc-abntex2 **TCC.tex is the main file**

This template give me many problems, but I'm still using it to help other people that can use it someday, and will not need to do this again.

**command on the top of the file TCC.tex**

```
\include{fixos/pacoteseclass}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
```

**Error message**

[image: Error message]

[image]

Comment: `abntex2.cls` is based on `memoir`, that used a different system. Remove `\usepackage{setspace}` and use `\OnehalfSpacing` or, if you absolutely need 1.5, say `\setSpacing{1.5}` *before* `\checkandfixthelayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`abntex2.cls` is based on `memoir`, that used a different system. Remove `\usepackage{setspace}` and use `\OnehalfSpacing` or, if you absolutely need 1.5, say `\setSpacing{1.5}` *before* `\checkandfixthelayout`.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
%\OnehalfSpacing % preferred
\setSpacing{1.5} % too much space
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @egreg, thanks for your answer. It works, but as the `\linespread` it changes the toc line space. It's possible that it doesn't?

Comment: @ItaloPessoa Add `\SingleSpacing` before `\tableofcontents` and `\setSpacing{1.5}` back after it.

Comment: Man thank you so much for you support. Everybody here is awesome